# Moderation Badges on Stack Overflow / Documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation, badges

Why don't some of the Moderation Badges on Stack Overflow get updated from Documentation? For example while we do get reputation points for edits on Documentation, they don't count toward the editing badges on Stack Overflow. Is this on purpose or are the Documentation badges going to come out with their own specific versions when applicable? Would someone get the Critic badge for a first downvote on Docs? The Backer badge (Documentation) has an equivalent version as Supporter on Stack Overflow. So what are the guidelines for these badges that can apply to both the Documentation and Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 3):

Eventually, we'll probably want a bunch of badges that correspond to constructive participation on Docs. Feel free to propose any ideas you might have here on meta...

...But first, we have a lot of work to do figuring out the basics, like what sorts of edits are constructive, how to combat bandwagon-jumping, where the rate-limits need to be, etc.

In Q&A, badges recognize editors as otherwise unsung-heroes. In Docs, the vast bulk of participation is editing, so badges should focus on encouraging behaviors that are beneficial but might not otherwise be obvious. What that means in practice remains to be seen...

Answer (score 1):

Considering these badges are listed *separately* on the [Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) page, I'd say that the badges will stay separate. There might be more to come, though.

For example, consider edits; they have a different function on the Q&A site, where they are meant to be minor improvements, leaving the intention of the post's author intact. For Documentation, we can expect edits to be a lot more substantial, even adding new angles to a topic. The different functions are reflected in a separation of badges.